# How to replace NaN values on a pandas subset of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I would like to replace the missing values on columns `C` and `D` from the following `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], 
                   "B": [1, np.nan, 3],
                   "C": [np.nan, 2, 3],
                   "D": [1, 2, np.nan]})

df


    A   B       C       D
0   1   1.00    nan     1.00
1   2   nan     2.00    2.00
2   3   3.00    3.00    nan
```

I can do it if go column by column replacing the values:

```
df["C"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df["D"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

However, if I try to do it on both columns at the same time I get a `SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`:

```
df[["C", "D"]].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

I have also tried to change the values using `.loc`, but it doesn't work either:

```
df.loc[:,["C", "D"]].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Is there any other way to replace the missing values in place without having to write a line of code for each column?

Comment: Read more about `SettingWithCopyWarning` on SO and you would understand why `inplace` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
fill_map = {col:0 for col in ['C', 'D']}
df = df.fillna(value=fill_map)
```

---

**df:**

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   1.0 0.0 1.0
1   2   NaN 2.0 2.0
2   3   3.0 3.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

While writing the question I have found a possible solution:

`df[["C", "D"]] = df[["C", "D"]].fillna(0)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because in one case you're working with a view of the dataframe, in the other you are using a copy.

`df["C"]` returns a view into df (a data series), so changing that with `.fillna(0, inplace=True)` changes the actual df dataframe.

`df[["C", "D"]]` however returns a copy of a part of df, as would `df[["C"]]`, incidentally, because of the double brackets. So if you change that with `.fillna(0, inplace=True)`, only the copy would get changed, so you don't see the change in the original df. That's why pandas gives the `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning.

The logic of whether the operation returns a view or a copy of the dataframe is not really intuitive. [This](https://www.practicaldatascience.org/html/views_and_copies_in_pandas.html) has some details on that.

Your own solution

```
df[["C", "D"]] = df[["C", "D"]].fillna(0)
```

works, because you're making a copy, filling it with zeros, and reassigning it to the original df.

Another solution when there's a larger list of columns would be:

```
cols = ['C', 'D']
for c in cols: df[c].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Also, there are a lot of answers on stackoverflow, on exactly this topic. Just search for fillna.